# How to add a scalebar without displaying the image in dm-script

Tags: annotations, dm-script

How do I add annotations, in particular a scalebar, to an image without showing the image?

---

I have an application that records images. I want to add a scalebar to every recoreded image. But the users can choose not to display recorded images. This is why I want to add the scalebar before and independently of showing the image.

The docs recommend to use `ImageDocumentSaveToFile()` for saving. Hence I am creating an image document for the image. Since the scalebar is added to the image display, I also add an image display (if there is no display given). But when I save the image document and load it again, I get the following error:

[image: Error: That operation requires an image document containing exactly one image]

That tells me that somewhere I am adding the image twice to the image document. But I don't get where (code posted below).

[image: Screenshot of opening the image manually]

I can open the image manually from the path it is saved to. The image shows the content (plain color here) but does not show a scalebar (screenshot shown above). So I guess I somehow add two displays or images where one contains the scalebar and the other does not. But I don't know how to go on now and how to solve this problem.

My stripped down code is posted below.

---

So my question is: What in my code causes the scalebar not to show up and what causes GMS to raise an error when opening the image? Or even better, what is the best practice to add annotations to images without showing them?

---

```c
number image_width = 128;
number image_height = 128;
image img := RealImage("Image",  4, image_width, image_height);
img = 128;

ImageDocument doc = img.ImageGetOrCreateImageDocument();

void addScalebar(ImageDisplay display){
    number top = image_height - image_height / 5;
    number bottom = image_height;
    number left = 0;
    number right = image_width / 3;
    Component scalebar = NewComponent(31, top, left, bottom, right);
    scalebar.ComponentSetForegroundColor(0, 255, 0);
    display.ComponentAddChildAtBeginning(scalebar);
}

image tmp_img;
for(number i = 0; i < doc.ImageDocumentCountImages(); i++){
    tmp_img = doc.ImageDocumentGetImage(i);
    
    if(tmp_img.ImageCountImageDisplays() > 0){
        for(number j = 0; j < tmp_img.ImageCountImageDisplays(); j++){
            addScalebar(tmp_img.ImageGetImageDisplay(j));
        }
    }
    else{
        ImageDisplay disp = doc.ImageDocumentAddImageDisplay(tmp_img, -2);
        addScalebar(disp);
    }
}

string save_format = "Gatan Format";
string path = PathConcatenate(GetApplicationDirectory("temporary", 1), "demo-image");
doc.ImageDocumentSaveToFile(save_format, path);

string open_path;
ImageDocumentAdjustFileNameForSaveFormat(save_format, path, open_path);
result("Demo image is located at '" + open_path + "'\n");

image display_image := OpenImage(open_path);
display_image.ShowImage();
```

---

<sup>The posted code is written in `dm-script`. My original code is written in python and this is a more-less direct translation to `dm-script` which may be easier to understand for the [dm-script](/questions/tagged/dm-script). Plus I feel it to be "more general" to post the question in `dm-script`. The problem applies for both programming languages and I hope that the solution does as well. If not and if you know the python implementation I am also happy to see it.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for posting this as 'dm-script' as it indeed is easier to see here. (And the solution applies for Python as well.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very nice script.
You fell into a typical *DM beginner's* pitfall, where the scripting language unfortunately has a very non-standard syntax.

> There is a difference between:
>
> `tmp_img = doc.ImageDocumentGetImage(i);`
>
> and:
>
> `tmp_img := doc.ImageDocumentGetImage(i);`

The second example is what you want to do: Have the image variable `tmp_img` point at the i-th image of the imageDocument.

The first example, however, *copies the data values* of the i-th image into a newly created image. This newly created image does not have an imageDisplay! Which is why your code-example branches off into the 'else' statement.

Note also, that you don't need that if/else if you fix the line beforehand. ImageDocuments can't hold images, they hold imageDisplays (which are tied to images).
More specific: ImageDocuments have a root-component that, like all components, can have children-components. ImageDisplays are also components.

Comment: This is the answer for my qustion. Still it makes everything worse for the python implementation since python does not know references. I will try my best but I may open another question with the exact same content except the code is python. I thought I could fix it when I know the `dm-script` solution :(

Comment: I already tried the "oneliner" `image_document.GetRootComponent().GetNthChildOfType(20, 0).AddNewComponent(31, top, left, bottom, right)` but unfortunately that doesn't work. Probably there a reference breaks inside the `dm-script` python module or something.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer for the Python variant of the problem.
The following could should do what you want (in Python):

```py
import numpy as np
imgArray = np.arange(200000).reshape(400, 500).copy(order='C')
testImg = DM.CreateImage(imgArray)

doc = testImg.GetOrCreateImageDocument()
doc.GetRootComponent().GetNthChildOfType(20, 0).AddNewComponent(31, 10,10,40,400)

path = 'C:/temp/uniqueName3.dm4'
doc.SaveToFile('Gatan Format',path)


# Cleanup 
del testImg
del doc
```